# How can I cast negative double to ulong in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I found a code snippet in C++ that is `uint x=(uint)k * 100;` which k is a float either positive or negative. And I must implement this code in C#. I write this code as `ulong x = Convert.ToUInt64(k * 100)` whick k is a positive or negative double in this case. So when k is positive code is working but if k is negative it gives error. However I am completely sure the C++ one is correct. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: What behaviour do you expect when `k` is negative?   For example, if `k` is `-11.2345`, what value do you expect `x` to have?   [Or, to put it another way, what result does `Convert.ToUInt64(k*100)` produce when `k` is negative?]

Comment: I don't know, I expect exactly what C++ solution will be return.

Comment: @Ardahan Kisbet, you don't have to use `Convert.ToUInt64`, do same casting you did in `c++`

Comment: Sorry, Ardahan, but that's not sufficient.   There are plenty of "C++ solutions" that will do different things with negative values.    If you haven't thought about what your code will DO with `x` when `k` is negative, there is no point in doing the conversion.

Comment: It has no matter what is going on with those x and k variables. It should return unsigned positive long when gave it a negative double. I don't know what should return because I currently developing program and before checking returning value it gave the error. After these below suggestions I will know what should return. Hope this is clear what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint` or `ulong` are **unsigned**. That means that they can take values starting from 0. They cannot take negative values. So when you write `Convert.ToUInt64(negative_double)` it gives the following execption:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

If you still want to perform this assignment you can do same cast you do in `c++`

```
ulong x = (ulong)k * 100;
```

> I don't know, I expect exactly what C++ solution will be return.

It will give you the same `c++` result.

Comment: Thank you, this will work more correctly I guess. Or is there any difference between casting or using convertTo method?

Comment: @Ardahan Kisbet, Yes. The difference exists and you can observe it. `Convert.ToUInt64` will throw `System.OverflowException` when value is not convertible. Casting will just give a note to compiler that you know what you are doing and will just take the bytes from the variable and interpret them in another way.

Comment: Thank you so much I will think about that and pick one of them.

Comment: @Ardahan Kisbet, consider [accepting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Since converting a negative value to an unsigned UInt64 is an error, you'll have to convert to a signed Int64 and then just cast over to the UInt64 you need to get the same result as in C++;

```
var result = (UInt64)Convert.ToInt64 (k * 100);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly convert from a double to an unsigned long, you first have to convert to a long. So try this:

```
ulong x = (ulong)(long)k * 100;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3d6fhea%28v=vs.120%29.aspx